# How to create Monolithic lists from array in increasing order (sub-Lists)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have to create a monolithic list from an array in increasing order in c#. I was given `[1 2 4 7 5 6 3 2]` as test input whose test output is `[[1 2 4 7] [5 6] [3] [2]]`. The thing is i am **not at all** able to understand what question is and what it is asking me to do so that i start.

Could some one please me what is monolithic mean in current scenario of array ? and how these 4 array output produced from the input array ?

**Edit** I have understood how these sublists are created upon input array, they are created when `input[i]>input[i+1]`. But how to code such dynamic sublists inside lists ?

Comment: It appears that it is creating an array of arrays where each subarray starts over as soon as you find an entry that is lower than the previous.  In your input, since `7>5`, then 5 starts a new sub-array.  Since `6>3`, 3 starts a new sub-array, etc.

Comment: How come you don't ask your `Instructor || Boss || Supervisor`

Comment: @MethodMan It was a question i found on internet, couldnt' understand so i asked, But how to implement it ? (We have to do something list inside list, dynamically)

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks you caught in first glimpse, i couldn't . But the issue would be how to implement such dynamic lists inside list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old fashioned way:

```
List<int> sublist=new List<int>();
int last=Int32.MinValue;
List<int[]> list=new List<int[]>();
foreach(var i in input)
{
   if(i<last) 
   {
     list.Add(sublist.ToArray());
     sublist=new List<int>();
   }
   last=i;
   sublist.Add(i);
}
list.Add(sublist.ToArray());
var answer=list.ToArray();
```

The newer way would be to return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` that is traversed only when enumerated, and is much better, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you or someone else to do.

Comment: Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'sublist' at line 
list.Add(sublist.ToArray());

Comment: And i think your algo is not correct, it will print just [6,3,2] at 5th index of "var answer" the rest index will be zero values.Please note that there is comparison of input[i] and input[i+1] , i mean something like if(input[i]<input[i+1]).

Comment: Updated answer with fixes -- and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Java Solution:

```
public  List<List<Integer>> createMonolithic(List<Integer> list){

            List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

                if(i - 1 >=0){

                    if(list.get(i) < list.get(i-1)){

                        result.add(r);
                        r = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        r.add(list.get(i));

                    }else{
                        r.add(list.get(i));
                    }

                }else{
                    r.add(list.get(i));
                }

            }
            result.add(r);
            return result;
        }
```